# Como usar UpdatePanel no gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Tenho um grid e quero fazer ele não dar `postback` quando clicado em algum `boundfield` (aqueles botões de ações).
Fiz dessa maneira abaixo, mas sempre atualiza a pagina.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" .. ETC />
                <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Excluir" />                
                </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Por que você usa `UpdateMode="Conditional"`?

Answer (score 1):

Mude o atributo `ChildrenAsTriggers` para `false`.

Esse atributo faz com que todos os controles filhos causem o `PostBack`.

Se precisar que algum controle específico seja usado como gatilho, configure-o da seguinte forma:

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Ou, se quiser ter um controle mais refinado de quando o UpdatePanel deve ser atualizado, no codebehind chame:

```
 meuUpdatePanel.Update();
```